# Prove $f(x)>\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question:** Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a$, and $f(a)>\lambda$, then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)>\lambda$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.

If it is continuous at $a$, then by definition, given any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$, for all $x \in X$, whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.

$$\varepsilon > |f(x)-f(a)| \geq |f(x)| - |f(a)|$$

But I can't do anything after this because the last term is minus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Take $$\varepsilon = f(a) - \lambda> 0$$

Comment: how do you even know that is greater than zero for all values of lambda and f(a)

Comment: @snowman By hypothesis you have $f(a) > \lambda$.

Comment: just curious, how did you know right away to take that approach?

Comment: @snowman Time and practice! I've seen this trick lots of times in analysis.